# timeout on ajax loading javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

Looking through the forum since last 4 hours but can find the answer so posting question now. 
I am loading JS with jQuery ajax using similar code as mentioned on this forum as below to set timeout if JS fails to load in 300ms but even though I get in the error funtion and in timeout condition the file still load. I try to set the timeout to 1 ms and I can see in console that that file is not loaded in 1 ms but after sometime it loads. So, not able to abort the ajax function once the request is in timeout.

```
var loadScript = function(url) {

   $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        timeout: 1,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log('Loaded')
        },
        error: function(request, status, err) {
            if (status == "timeout") {
                console.log('timeout');
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, but I am hoping to make it work in all major browser.

Comment: In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.  from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/